# how to get wordpress post id externally?

Tags: php, wordpress

in a php script which is basically **unaware of the page it's inserted in**, how could I get the post ID if I'm using permalinks, so - *url_to_postid( $url );* is out of the question, also, using *global $post;* won't help either.

The only place in my html where the id is shown is in the body tag as class"... postid-7777 .."

If I'm inserting specific ID directly it works, but I need it to look for the ID automatically so that "related posts" could be shown...

I'm not a php programmer (yet) so I'd really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Use the wordpress global $post (as long as you are inside the loop) to get the id and other information about the current post.

More information here:

[Wordpress Codex - Post Global](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post)

Comment: dude, please read through what I wrote: "using global $post; won't help either."...

Comment: sorry - missed that. Why can't you use the global $post?

Comment: well, I'm using ajax to insert the code on page scroll, in order for the php code to work I have _require_once("../../../wp-load.php");_ and then the code.   so it seems the code is basically unaware of the global $post since it echos nothing...
Maybe there's a file I can include which will make the code aware of globals? (already tried wp_blog_header.php - didn't work at all)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [get_queried_object()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object).
There is also get_queried_object_id(), both worked several times for me.

Comment: So whats meant by unaware of its page? Where are you trying to get the ID?

Comment: well, I'm using ajax to insert the code on page scroll, in order for the php code to work I have require_once("../../../wp-load.php"); and then the code. so it seems the code is basically unaware of the globals and:
$page_object = get_queried_object();
$page_id     = get_queried_object_id();
only returns zero

Comment: Ahh that explains alot, take a look at http://solislab.com/blog/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/ may it will help you.

Comment: thanks mate, I actually already been in that page but perhaps this time I should look into it more throughly.